# Retrieve properties from json response

Tags: javascript, json

After ajax call I am trying to extract data properties - message content of the first element:

```
success : function(data) {

console.log(data[0].message);
console.log(data);
console.log(data.message); .....}


undefined
[{"message":"Must not "},{"message":"hello"}]
undefined
```

Following tutorial http://www.copterlabs.com/blog/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/ I am very confused of what I am doing wrong. While last `data.message` is clearly invalid, I see nothing wrong with `data[0].message`...

Comment: what's `typeof (data)` ?

Comment: @WayneWang You hit the spot.. damn. It was text. I was expecting error if my return type is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is still int he form of a string. Add `var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);` to your `success` function to convert it to a Javascript object

You haven't shown your AJAX call, but jQuery's `.getJSON()` will parse the data for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a "json.js" from below link

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

And call

```
var json = JSON.parse(data);
```

to extract the data in form of a Object. Here is an example.

http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Answer (score -3):

I think that you receive string but not the JSON object
Use eval(data) for this string

Comment: Er no - do not use `eval` for this. Use `JSON.parse()`: it's faster & much safer.